# How to debug vendor classes in laravel

Tags: laravel, debugging

I am using Bllim dataTable package for data table and when I am searching the record there is some errors that keep cropping up. I need to debug the class file which is located in the `vendor folder`.

So i added `use Illuminate Log` in datatables.php but it keeps throwing me a class not found error. Can someone share how to debug the `vendor class` files OR if I want to add the default Log inside this package. It would be great help

Comment: I suggest you look into using an actual debugger such as [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org) to do debugging efficiently.

Comment: It is very extensive debugging , I simply want to Log some variables ... Log::info will be more helpful I guess

Comment: It depends what file of the package you want to include the logger. Normally, if the file you want to include the logger in, is executed after Laravel has set up its service providers, you can just include the logger facade. So you can just add `use Log;` at the top of the file and then use the logger normally with `Log::debug()`, `Log::info()`, etc.